# Getting class as undefined for img tag in react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, components

Getting class as undefined for img tag in react.js
This is the component Header.jsx,
Here is the Header.jsx I'm using `<img>`, but the CSS properties are not not being implemented in the image, and I'm getting error as `class=undefined`

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './header.css';
import { Box,Grid, Typography} from '@mui/material';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs>
            <img src='./images/logo.svg' className={`${classes.header__logo}`} alt='Logo'/>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Typography>gbr</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs>
              <Typography>gbr</Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}

export default Header
```

This is the css file for the header

```
/* header.css */

.header__logo{
    height: 20px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

In the console I'm getting this error, `class="undefined"`

```
<img src="./images/logo.svg" class="undefined" alt="Logo">
```

Comment: You are using a CSS module feature without making `header.css` a module. Try renaming the file as `header.module.css`

Comment: @MelvinAbraham I think he struggles with material-ui old version. Your concept work in next js.

Answer (score 0):

**Just do like that:Basic Concept**

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.css';
import { Box,Grid, Typography} from '@mui/material';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs>
            <img src='./images/logo.svg' className="header__logo" alt='Logo'/>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Typography>gbr</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs>
              <Typography>gbr</Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 0):

When im doing this naming convention I make sure there's a parent tag with the classname you're trying to extend, in this case "header", also helps if your using SCSS with this, try something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './header.scss';
import { Box,Grid, Typography} from '@mui/material';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className={`${classes.header}`>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs>
            <img src='./images/logo.svg' className={`${classes.header__logo}`} alt='Logo'/>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Typography>gbr</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs>
              <Typography>gbr</Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Inside your './header.scss'

```
.header {
  // css style for header class

  &__logo {
    // css style code for logo class
  }
}
```

I find, it returns undefined because it wasn't properly placed in the correct spot within your style sheet. Your react code looks good just missing a few things.